# Generate a list holding/making mapping between a List<string> and a List<int>

Tags: c#, linq

This i probably a simple question, but I'm still new to C# and LINQ (which I assume is useful in this case).

I have a List with different groups:

```
e.g. List<string>() { a, a, b, c, a, b, b };
```

I would like to make a corresponding List (sort of GroupID), holding:

```
List<int>() { 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2}
```

The amount of different groups could be anything from 1-x, so a dynamic generation of the List is needed. Duplicate groups should get same numbers.

All this should end up in a LINQ zip() of the two into 'CombinedList', and a SqlBulkCopy with other data to a database with a foreach.

```
table.Rows.Add(data1, data2, data3, CombinedList.GroupID.toString() ,CombinedList.Group.ToString());
```

Hope it makes sense.

Example:

```
List<string>() { a, a, b, c, a, b, b };
```

This list holds 3 unique groups: a, b and c.

assign an incrementing number to the groups, starting from 1:

```
a = 1, b = 2, c = 3.
```

The generated result list should then hold

```
List<string>() { 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2 };
```

Comment: Get distinct values, sort (optionally) => list where index is `GroupID`.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I think I wasn't clear. Sorry. I just need to generate a List <int> holding af int generated based on the  GroupList. First encounted group should get the 1, second 2 etc. So all similar groups have same GroupID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me:

```
var source = new List<string>() { "a", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "b" };

var map =
    source
        .Distinct()
        .Select((x, n) => new { x, n })
        .ToDictionary(xn => xn.x, xn => xn.n + 1);

var result =
    source
        .Select(x => new { GroupIP = map[x], Value = x });
```

I get this result:

[image: result]

Comment: I will test this when possible, probably not until monday. But I will return. Looks like it is what I'm looking for! thx

Comment: Nice solution posted!  and looks like linqpad :)

Comment: @Kix - Thanks, and yes it is LINQPad. I use it for almost all my coding now.

Answer (score 1):

Generate a List:

```
var strings = new List<string>() { "a", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "b" };
var uniqueStrings = strings.Distinct().ToList();
var numbers = strings.Select(s => uniqueStrings.IndexOf(s)).ToList();
```

This produces:

```
List<int> { 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 1 }
```

If you want to have your values starting at 1 instead of 0, then modify the last line to include `+1` as per below:

```
var numbers = strings.Select(s => uniqueStrings.IndexOf(s) + 1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think this can help you.

```
        var keyValue = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
        var listString = new List<string>() { "a", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "b"};
        var listInt = new List<int>();
        int count = 1;

        foreach (var item in listString)
        {

            if(keyValue.Count(c=>c.Value == item) == 0)
            {
                keyValue.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(count, item));
                count++;
            }
        }

        foreach (var item in listString)
        {
            listInt.Add(keyValue.Single(s=>s.Value == item).Key);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
int groupId = 1;
var list = new List<string>() { "a", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "b" };
var dict = list
     .GroupBy(x => x)
     .Select(x => new {Id = groupId++, Val = x})
     .ToDictionary(x => x.Val.First(), x => x.Id);
var result = list.Select(x => dict[x]).ToList();
```